# React Animations with VelocityJS

Tags: coffeescript, reactjs

I'm having a really hard time getting animations to work in React. Perhaps there is something I'm fundamentally missing.

I'm doing this in coffeescript -- I hope you don't mind.

I've created a very simple UI. Theres a div with a title in it. When you click the title, the title is changed, and I want to animate a fade in/out transition using VelocityJS.

```
ReactTransitionGroup = React.createFactory(React.addons.CSSTransitionGroup)

{div} = React.DOM

TitleClass = React.createClass
  displayName: "Title"
  render: ->
    (div {onClick:@props.changeTitle}, @props.title)

  componentWillEnter: (done) ->
    node = @getDOMNode()
    console.log "willEnter"
    Velocity(node, 'transition.fadeIn', {complete: done})

  componentWillLeave: (done) ->
    node = @getDOMNode()
    console.log "willLeave"
    Velocity(node, 'transition.fadeOut', {complete: done})


Title = React.createFactory(TitleClass)

MainClass = React.createClass
  displayName: "Main"
  getInitialState: ->
    title: 'Main'
  changeTitle: ->
    if @state.title is 'Home'
      @setState {title: 'Main'}
    else
      @setState {title: 'Home'}
  render: ->
    (div {style:{width: '100%', fontSize:'25px', textAlign:'center', marginTop:'20px'}},
      (ReactTransitionGroup {transitionName: 'fade'},
        (Title {changeTitle:@changeTitle, title:@state.title})
      )
    )

Main = React.createFactory(MainClass)

React.render(Main({}), document.body)
```

So thats it. Pretty self explanatory. This `ReactTransitionGroup` is still quite a mystery to me. It is my understanding that any of its children should get calls to `componentWillEnter` and `componentWillLeave` but that doesn't end up happening. [According to the docs](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html#low-level-api-reacttransitiongroup) it seems that I should see the `console.log "willEnter"` but I don't.

I've been hung up on this for hours. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution ends up being to use `React.addons.TransitionGroup`. The `CSSTransitionGroup` is just a wrapper that does CSS stuff.

The other issue is that to get the animation callbacks, the children must have a key!

```
ReactTransitionGroup = React.createFactory(React.addons.TransitionGroup)

# {clip}

(ReactTransitionGroup {transitionName: 'fade'},
  (Title {changeTitle:@changeTitle, title:@state.title, key:'title'})
)
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems I can see in your code above.

The first one is that you are using `React.addons.CSSTransitionGroup` instead of `React.addons.TransitionGroup`.

The second problem is that you are expecting `componentWillEnter` to get triggered on mount when in fact `componentWillAppear` is the method being triggered.

Answer (score 0):

CSSTransitionGroup watches for actual uses of the CSS `transition` property written onto the elements. I'm not sure exactly how, but it sounds like Velocity isn't doing its work in a way that CSSTransitionGroup is twigging to. You may have to call `componentWillEnter` and `componentWillLeave` manually. In this situation, it doesn't sound like that'll be hard.

**EDIT:** oops, I missed that you don't have `key` attributes on your child components in the group. From what I can tell, `componentWillEnter` and `componentWillLeave` should get called, irrespective of anything else, if you get keys on those kids.

Comment: You're saying like this `(Title {changeTitle:@changeTitle, key: 'navtitle', title:@state.title})`? Still not getting the callbacks :/